# GDAL 3 installed, but Geo PDF greyed out on Mac

Tags: gdal, mac, geopdf

I still can't export a GEOPDF.

I am running QGIS 3.16 with GDAL 3 installed on a Mac with OSX Big Sur, but the GeoPDF option is still greyed out. It says, "No GDAL PDF Driver available."

Does anyone have a fix for this?

[image: About QGIS]

Comment: How did you build GDAL (or which installer did you use to install it)?  GDAL has many options for building, including various optional libraries which are required for some of the functionality.  For GeoPDF, GDAL needs to be explicitly built against either Poppler, PoDoFo or PDFium (see:  https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html)

Comment: I used the kyngchaos package installer.

Comment: I haven’t used that one for years, and I don’t know how it was built.   Does it include those PDF dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure how'd I'd figure that out. Where would I look for that? I'm guessing it doesn't. If that's the case could I install a different GDAL version?

Comment: I can’t recall if that build’s website has the info or not.  But yes, the solution would be to build GDAL yourself, and to explicitly include all the libraries that you need.   But this is a non-trivial exercise for any software, and GDAL is more complex to build than many others.  I’ve not built v3, only v2 a long time ago.

Comment: The Kyngchaos page at https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/ says, "PDF read support is not available at this time, I am working on it".  So it doesn't even have PDF read support, let alone PDF write support.

Comment: Which build of QGIS are you using?  The standard QGIS installer for macOS is an all-in-one installer that has GDAL built in, I think, anyhow.  So it may not even use your separate install of GDAL.  OR are you using the KyngChaos QGIS build (or some other build)?

Comment: KyngChaos bulid. I wanted the ability to use GRASS and some of the other features and have had a hard time getting things to work with the all in one build. I can always export a geotiff and use it the same way as a geopdf for what I need. I was just hoping to have the vector layers save for clarity when zooming in.