# QGIS: GeoPDF - no GDAL PDF is not available

Tags: qgis, gdal, pdf, geopdf

I use QGIS 3.18 and when I try to export my maps as GeoPDF, the space "create a GeoPDF" remains grey I can't click on it and the message: "no GDAL PDF pilot available" is written under.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether your GDAL library has PDF support built in. Here's a possibly related question, specific to using QGIS on a Mac with the KyngChaos builds (at the time of writing, those used a GDAL library without PDF support): [GDAL 3 installed, but Geo PDF greyed out on Mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412926/gdal-3-installed-but-geo-pdf-greyed-out-on-mac)

If you have GDAL installed, go to the command line and check that the PDF format is supported by the library. In a linux bash shell, the following will work:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep -i pdf
```

If your GDAL library supports GeoPDF, a line of output will list the PDF format and if read and write are supported.

If you don't have GDAL, installing that will be your first step.